# Import CSV file in MySQL (update) with PHP

Tags: mysql, csv

I have CSV file with ID and size field - ID is not in all rows - only first (see below):

```
ID1;40
   ;41
   ;42
   ;43
ID2;26
   ;27
ID3;34
   ;35
   ;36
   ;37
   ;38
   ;39
```

I need ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE record in MySQL database with two columns - ID and sizes:

```
ID    SIZES
---------------------
ID1   40;41;42;43
ID2   26;27
ID3   34;35;36;37;38;39
```

All sizes for one ID are in one value/field.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table into which your data will be imported.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE my_table (
     id   VARCHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
     size INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(id, size)
   );
   ```
2. Import the data, handling the non-repetition of the `ID` column using user variables.

   ```
   SET @old_id := NULL;

   LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
       INTO my_table
       FIELDS
           TERMINATED BY ';'
       (@new_id, size)
       SET id = (@old_id := IF(CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(@new_id))>0, @new_id, @old_id))
   ;
   ```
3. Retrieve the data, grouping as desired.

   ```
   SELECT   id, GROUP_CONCAT(size SEPARATOR ';') AS sizes
   FROM     my_table
   GROUP BY id;
   ```